# VS 2017 Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2017

VS 2015 Selenium works fine both in home office and at work with the chrome driver. At Home office, the Firefox and Edge drivers work fine with the following code:

```
            [Test]
    public void FirefoxTest()
    {
        IWebDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver(); //Broken

        firefoxDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://www.google.com");
        firefoxDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        firefoxDriver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).Clear();
        firefoxDriver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("selenium \n");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Assert.IsTrue((firefoxDriver.FindElement(By.Id("resultStats")).Text ?? "").Contains("About"));

        firefoxDriver.Close();
        firefoxDriver.Quit();

    }



    [Test]
    public void EdgeTest()
    {
        IWebDriver edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver();
        edgeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"http://www.google.com");
        edgeDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        edgeDriver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).Clear();
        edgeDriver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("selenium \n");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Assert.IsTrue((edgeDriver.FindElement(By.Id("resultStats")).Text ?? "").Contains("About"));
        edgeDriver.Close();
        edgeDriver.Quit();
    }
```

At the Office, using VS 2017, Chrome and IE work fine, Firefox and Edge do not.
The Firefox driver instantiates and launches the browser, but then locks up and never returns to the calling code. The next line to navigate never gets called.

The Edge driver continues to error with the message OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:42623.

Both test have been reconfigured incorporating suggested solutions including FirefoxOptions, FirefoxProfile, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is about software version. You should update all the drivers and browsers.

Comment: Thanks, but its not obvious to me where the mismatch is: Firefox 58.0.1 (64-bit)
geckodriver.exe v 0.19.1 – 32 bit
geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64

Microsoft Edge 41.16299.15.0
Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299

Microsoft WebDriver Release 16299 Version: 5.16299 | Edge version supported: 16.16299 

NUnit v3.9.0
Selenium.WebDriver v3.8.0
Selenium.Firefox.Webdriver v0.19.1
Selenium.RC v3.1.0
Windows 10 Pro -  Version 1709 - OS Build 16299.192